# Syntax error. Statement labels are only allowed in SystemVerilog

Tags: verilog

Modelsim: I check many times, but I could not find out how to fix it.

> near ":": Syntax error. Statement labels are only allowed in SystemVerilog.

```
 parameter [1:0] S1 = 2'b00, S2 = 2'b01, S3 = 2'b10;
        always @(cur_state or s or Cout or cnt_zero) // Combo logic for
        begin: FSM_outputs  // output signals
            load_R = 0; en_shift_R = 0; rr0mux = 0; 
            load_cnt = 0; en_cnt = 0; en_shift_A = 0; 
                case (cur_state)
                    S1: begin
                            load_cnt = 1; en_shift_R = 1; 
                            if (s == 0) begin 
                                load_R = 1; rr0mux = 0; 
                           end
                           else begin
                                load_R = 0; en_shift_A = 1; rr0mux = 1;
                           end
                    S2: begin //the errors are located HERE S2.
                            Rmux = 1; en_shift_R = 1; rr0mux = 1; en_shift_A = 1; 
                            if (Cout) load_R = 1;
                            else load_R = 0;
                            if (cnt_zero == 0) en_cnt = 1;
                            else en_cnt = 0;
                           end
                    S3: done = 1;
                endcase 
            end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing an `end` keyword after `S1` state description:

```
S1: 
begin
  load_cnt = 1; en_shift_R = 1; 
  if (s == 0) begin 
    load_R = 1; rr0mux = 0; 
  end
  else begin
    load_R = 0; en_shift_A = 1; rr0mux = 1;
  end
end //missing end
```

That's why your IDE is treating `S2: begin` as a statement label and you receive an error.